# how to use `less` to read mail in linux?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sendmail

when I run `mail` to check my email in `/var/mail/ubuntu`, I can't scroll the page.

I can just use `space` key to jump one page, but cannot use the direction key or `jk` to scroll up and down. There must be a method to set the `less` command to be the reader of mail. Who can help me?

Comment: What's wrong with `pine`?

Comment: Or use `mutt` after having configured it. Or configure a mail user agent, perhaps even a GUI one like `evolution` or `icedove`

Answer (score 1):

In Mail, you can use less as such...

```
& set PAGER=less
```

Then do something like...

```
& from 1-100
```

Answer (score 1):

export PAGER=less

then in mail the pager is 'less', G to the end, great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
mail -p | less
```

but for me it doesn't make much sense, because the interactive commands of mail are much stronger than piping the output of mail to less. If you like to learn the interactive commands you can find a nice explanation [here](http://www.johnkerl.org/doc/mail-how-to.html).

Comment: PS: I think there isn't a scrolling through mails like with less, but you can use z and z- to scroll through pages.